# hibernate annotations class for composite unique key

Tags: hibernate

I require help regarding creating annotation pojo class using hibernate for my table

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`TableName1`(  
   `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   `date` DATE NOT NULL, 
   `deskid` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   `systemid` BIGINT NOT NULL, 
   `fname` VARCHAR(10), 
   `lname` VARCHAR(10), 
   `role` VARCHAR(10), 
   `designation` VARCHAR(10), 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY (`date`,`deskid`,`systemid`)
)
```

how to create a composite unque key using hibernate annotation.

Comment: The primary key is `id`. You don't need a composite key.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the 'uniqueConstraints' attribute of `@Table` annotation.

For example:

```
@Table(name="PERSON", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"date","deskid","systemid"})})
```